# Remmina works once - after which it needs to be restarted part 2

Tags: manjaro, freerdp, remmina, rdp

Yes. This was originally intended to be a comment on [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/524708/remmina-works-once-after-which-it-needs-to-be-restarted) but I don't have permission to comment.

Probably better off as it's own question anyway.

I'm experiencing the same issue, in the same environment, with the same software, except for me the accepted solution (switch to freerdp-git) is even less tolerable than force-quitting the Remmina process between re-connection attempts.

This is because freerdp-git does not refresh the display properly, so I get little islands of the remote session being drawn onto my screen, but only when I force them to update by (ie: moving my mouse over them).

I did a quick google of the issue, but as you can tell by my 'little islands' comment, I'm not 100% sure what that is called, so I didn't get very far.

I also tried to get Remmina to run `pidof remmina | xargs kill` as a postcommand of my connection so that it'd clean up after itself and not make me kill it myself, but that only worked when I ran it manually, whether because the postcommand isn't getting run or because I've done it wrong I'm not sure (I did try as both a raw command and as a file reference to the script).

So I guess what I'm asking is:
A) Is there anything anyone can think of to fix the freerdp rendering issues, like a hidden little config switch or something?
B) Is there any way anyone can think of to actually properly force-quit remmina when the RDP Connection terminates?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is I'm a flipping idiot and didn't check the executability of the file.

Having a file:

```
#!/bin/bash
pidof remmina | xargs kill
```

and executing that file as a postcommand **is** all you need to tidy up Remmina when the connection fails/closes and allow re-connections straight away without having to manually terminate Remmina/freerdp.

Just be sure to chmod +x the file or Remmina will silently fail to execute it and it'll appear to not work.